# PHP show function results after calling the function

Tags: php

I am calling a PHP Function here:

```
<div class="box"><h2>Average Hold Time</h2><?php echo AverageHoldTime($queue_name, $date); ?></div>
```

Here is the actual function:

```
if(!function_exists("AverageHoldTime")) {
    function AverageHoldTime($queuename, $date) {
        global $pbx01_pdoconn;

        $stmt = $pbx01_pdoconn->prepare("SELECT avg(arg1) as avg_hold_time FROM ast_queue_log 
        WHERE queuename = :queuename 
        AND DATE(time) = :date 
        AND event = :event 
        ORDER BY time DESC ");
        $stmt->execute(array(':queuename' => $queuename, 
        ':date' => $date, 
        ':event' => 'CONNECT'));
        $result = $stmt->fetch();
        return gmdate("H:i:s", $result["avg_hold_time"]);
    }
}
```

but i want to be able to change the `.box` div to have a background colour if the returned result is  greater than X

UPDATE

How can i check if the result of the function is greater than X which is a value stored in a database.

I have a table called `alarms` which has the function names and then the values which the function returned results cannot go over otherwise it'll show the div background a different colour

how can i make it so my functions check if the returned result goes over the value in the alarms table

Answer (score 1):

You need the function to return the raw value:

```
function AverageHoldTime($queuename, $date) {
    global $pbx01_pdoconn;

    $stmt = $pbx01_pdoconn->prepare("SELECT avg(arg1) as avg_hold_time FROM ast_queue_log 
            WHERE queuename = :queuename 
            AND DATE(time) = :date 
            AND event = :event 
            ORDER BY time DESC ");
    $stmt->execute(array(':queuename' => $queuename, 
            ':date' => $date, 
            ':event' => 'CONNECT'));
    $result = $stmt->fetch();
    return $result["avg_hold_time"];
}
```

And do the date formatting afterwards:

```
<?php 
    $averageHoldTime = AverageHoldTime($queue_name, $date);
    // if $averageHoldTime is greater than 10, assign 'green' to $cssClass 
    $cssClass = $averageHoldTime > 10 ? 'green' : '';
?>

<div class="box <?php echo $cssClass; ?>">
    <h2>Average Hold Time</h2><?php echo gmdate("H:i:s", $averageHoldTime); ?>
</div>
```

I don't understand the part with the alarms table, but I would return both values from that function.

```
function AverageHoldTime($queuename, $date) {
    global $pbx01_pdoconn;

    $stmt = $pbx01_pdoconn->prepare("SELECT avg(arg1) as avg_hold_time FROM ast_queue_log 
                    WHERE queuename = :queuename 
                    AND DATE(time) = :date 
                    AND event = :event 
                    ORDER BY time DESC ");
    $stmt->execute(array(':queuename' => $queuename, 
                    ':date' => $date, 
                    ':event' => 'CONNECT'));
    $result = $stmt->fetch();

    return array(
        'avg_hold_time' => $result["avg_hold_time"],
        'alarm' => $some_value_from_alarms_table
    );
}

<?php 
        $data = AverageHoldTime($queue_name, $date);      
        $cssClass = $data['alarm'] > 10 ? 'green' : '';
?>
<div class="box <?php echo $cssClass; ?>">
    <h2>Average Hold Time</h2><?php echo gmdate("H:i:s", $data['avg_hold_time']); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: can you check my update please, i missed part out. hopefully it makes sense

Comment: about the alarms, basically what i said about i want to change the divs background if the returned value is greater than the alarm_value column in the alarms table where the function column in the alarms table is equal to the function name

Comment: does that make sense?